# Why is this bash script not splitting the string?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to split a string with two words delimited by spaces, and this snippet isn't working for me:

```
$ cat > test.sh
#/bin/bash
NP="3800 480"
IFS=" "
echo $NP
echo $NP | read VAR1 VAR2
echo "Var1 : $VAR1"
echo "Var2 : $VAR2"
exit 0
```

And invoking it gives me:

```
$ chmod 755 ./test.sh && ./test.sh
3800 480
Var1 :
Var2 :
```

Where I was hoping to see:

```
3800 480
Var1 : 3800
Var2 : 480
```

*How can a split a simple string like this in a bash script?*

**EDIT: (Answer I used)**
Thanks to the link provided by jw013, I was able to come up with this solution which worked for bash 2.04:

```
$ cat > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
NP="3800 480"
read VAR1 VAR2 << EOF
$NP
EOF
echo $VAR2 $VAR1

$./test.sh
480 3800
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the pipeline involves a fork, so you will want to make sure the rest of your script executes in the shell that does the read.

Just add `( ... )` as follows:

```
. . .
echo $NP | (read VAR1 VAR2
  echo "Var1 : $VAR1"
  echo "Var2 : $VAR2"
  exit 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Point and check.

Comment: But as a follow-on; how do I 'see' the variables outside the parenthesis?

Comment: Well, you could echo them back to the parent and capture them with command substitution. But the two scripts running after the pipeline are *both* near-identical copies of the original script, so why not just enclose the rest of the script in the parens? I suppose you could also call a shell procedure to execute the remaining functionality. The procedure could be defined outside the parens. (That is, outside the subshell.)

Answer (score 3):

With bash, you can use `<<<` (a "here string", redirect input from a string):

```
$ NP="3800 480"
$ read VAR1 VAR2 <<< $NP   # NB, variable is not quoted
$ echo $VAR2 $VAR1
480 3800
```

Comment: Intriguing, but unfortunately, I'm using bash 2.04 which gives me the error `syntax error near unexpected token '<<<'` when used inside a script.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
NP="3800 480"
IFS=" "
array=($NP)
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
```

would also work

Comment: Good, but a bash-only solution.

Comment: "Good, but a bash-only solution." - Which would be fine since the OP was asking for a bash solution. I'd even upvote this if eckes was invoking bash instead of bourne. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [BashFAQ 024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more about using `read` so that you can access the variables later.

My favorite solution (being more portable than the bash-only ones) is the here doc one:

```
read -r ... << EOF
$NP
EOF
```

Comment: Although you provided the answer I required, the answer to my main question was answered previously.  Thanks again though.